# Interpreting Metes and Bound description?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, cogo, metes-and-bounds, legal-description

I am trying to enter a metes and bounds description but it isn't plotting correctly. The description is:

> 5.3 acre parcel in the NW4, commencing at the Northest corner, thence South 789 ft to the place of beginning running thence: East 30 feet to
>   the East side of the present County Road; thence S. 17 degrees - 05'
>   E. 74 ft; thence S. 26-30 degrees E. 500 ft; thence S 1-40 degrees E
>   382 ft; thence S. 46 degrees W. 356 ft; thence West 30 feet to the
>   west line of the section; thence North 1148 ft to the place of
>   beginning.

The call I'm having a problem with is:

> thence South 789 ft to the place of beginning running thence: East 30
>   feet to the East side of the present County Road

See the image below. The parcel that I did with the metes/bound is in yellow, slightly below the Borie text. The parcel is supposed to be in the white/green box to its left.  I started my m/b off at "S 17-05 e / 74" and proceeded from there. It is supposed to be 5.3ac, but I am getting 4.7ac afterwards.

When I try putting in W / 30ft and then N and 1148 ft via metes/bounds, there is no movement.

What is it I should be doing or not doing? The ArcGIS 9.3 desktop help is not very helpful. How  does the "thence South 789 ft to the place of beginning running thence: East 30 feet to the East side of the present County Road;" AND "thence West 30 feet to the west line of the section; thence North 1148 ft to the place of beginning" come into play?

I'm using 9.3 ArcView if that helps.

[image]

Comment: I remember studying metes and bounds with townships back in College. Never thought I'd see that again.

Comment: I am probably wildly offbase, but I read it as: locate the northeast corner of NW4. Go South 789 ft, which puts you at POB, then east 30 ft which should get you to the east side of the county road, etc. It crosses the road to west at the end of the description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mkennedy is correct, your POB is 789' south of the NE corner of the NW4. Using that as your starting point you should see your other runs bring you back to within your expected area.

Comment: thank you.  I love doing metes/bounds as it just didn't look right for some reason and wanted to make sure as I'll make the adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

mkennedy is absolutely correct.  You might also consider using the TractBuilder Metes & Bounds Tool to make these types of descriptions even easier.  http://tractbuilder.com/tools_metes_bounds.html